# Как правильно написать Adapter для CardView и RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, adapter

У меня есть `CardView` с одним `ImageView` и тремя `TextView`, однако они не отображаются при запуске приложения. Как правильно дописать код, чтобы все получилось?. Вот код фрагмента,где должен быть `CardView`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.recycler_view, container, false);
    ContentAdapter adapter = new ContentAdapter(recyclerView.getContext());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    return recyclerView;
}
// toolbar
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true); // This Fragment has a menu
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_news, menu); // Inflate the Fragment's menu
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
// recycler
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CardView cv;
    TextView cvUser;
    TextView cvLocation;
    ImageView cvPhoto;
    TextView cvContent;

    public ViewHolder(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent) {
        super(inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_feed, parent, false));
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        cvUser = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_user);
        cvLocation = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_location);
        cvPhoto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_image);
        cvContent = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_text);
    }
}
public static class ContentAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder> {
    // Установим количество элементов списка в RecyclerView.
    private static final int LENGTH = 18;

    public ContentAdapter(Context context) {
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // no-op
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return LENGTH;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы данная реализация `RecyclerView` заработала, необходимо связывать `ViewHolder` в методе `onBindViewHolder` с поступившими данными. И потом, никакие данные для связки в класс `ContentAdapter` не передаются, на экран выводить нечего.

Comment: Предполагается, что у Вас в проекте должен быть класс-модель (Class Model) где и хранится изображение и текстовые данные. Эти данные в виде списка надо передать в конструктор вашего адаптера, ну и далее реализовать связь данных в  onBindViewHolder: Model model = listData.get(position); holder.bindData(model); и далее, уже в Вашем классе ViewHolder: расписываете метод void bindData(Model model){cv.setText(model.getText()); // и так далее}

Comment: а есть пример, чтобы проще было?

Comment: Скачай книгу Харди Б., Филлипс Б., Стюарт К., Марсикано К. - Android. Программирование для профессионалов, 2016. Там есть глава с подробным изложением реализации RecyclerView